# Why does an error #130 appear in production mode (React.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

This is strange, my app works perfect in the dev mode, but I got this error in the production mode:

```
`react-dom.production.min.js:209 Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

at Cl (react-dom.production.min.js:275)

at s (react-dom.production.min.js:141)

at h (react-dom.production.min.js:144)

at v (react-dom.production.min.js:145)

at react-dom.production.min.js:149

at Aa (react-dom.production.min.js:173)

at Da (react-dom.production.min.js:175)

at mu (react-dom.production.min.js:263)

at sl (react-dom.production.min.js:246)

at ul (react-dom.production.min.js:246)

eu @ react-dom.production.min.js:209`
```

I removed node_modules and installed it again and nothing happened.

Comment: can you put webpack configurations also?

Comment: It's the default react build configuration file

Comment: According to the message at the other end of that URL, it's an issue with trying to render an invalid component type: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."

Comment: Yeah, I read it, I googled the problem and I found that is a babel bug

Comment: Do I have to wait until the bug fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems babel has a bug when rendering components inside their parent class component. So to fix this issue, I had to change my class Child components to individual functional components, I used props to do this.